# flutter calling function slow my navigation to another screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I want to navigate from the P1 screen to P2. And P1 contains a button to move to p2.
P2 contain a function to get files. when i pass that function inside initState. navigation get slow.
**this is my function**

```
     Future<void> getFiles() async {
    await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
    if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
      // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it.
    }
    //asyn function to get list of files
    List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
    var root = storageInfo[0]
        .rootDir; //storageInfo[1] for SD card, getting the root directory
    var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //
    files = await fm.filesTree(
        excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/ssssssssssss"],
        extensions: ["pdf"] //optional, to filter files, list only pdf files
        );

    setState(() {}); //update the UI
  }
```

**initstate**

```
void initState() {
getFiles(); //call getFiles() function on initial state.
super.initState();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Isolate if this function is time taking it is effecting the main thread.

Comment: how can i fix this. cuz it stuck for sec wile navigating from P1 to P2

Comment: plaese add the code for P2 and how you are calling P1.

Comment: shared..........

Comment: okay, now try to comment the code which is causing stuck in the function itself.

Comment: dont know which code is stucking but this is the function to get all pdf and when i tap on a button in P1 . stuck for a sec and navigate to p2 and show all pdf

Comment: inside p2 i just call getfiles function inside initState

Comment: first try to comment this one then check

 files = await fm.filesTree(
        excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/ssssssssssss"],
        extensions: ["pdf"] //optional, to filter files, list only pdf files
        );

Comment: if this is not causing stuck also comment this line too " var fm = FileManager(root: Directory(root)); //" and so on

Comment: just need to know line which is causing stuck

Comment: is this possible that im also geeting stuck cux of listview where im listing this data

Comment: maybe, but if this function is causing stuck we need to know the line which is causing it.

Comment: if you try to keep commenting the line from bottom to top then we can get that code line causing stuck,

Comment: files = await fm.filesTree(
        excludedPaths: ["/storage/emulated/0/ssssssssssss"],

Comment: this is the line that causing stuck

Comment: Okay, so we need to work on this line of code, just wait please.

Comment: ok im waiting....

Comment: not stuck at every time but go back tap go back tap then...

Comment: listview is fine only this line of code inside function creating problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250048/discussion-between-faizan-abbas-bangash-and-ionicfirebaseapp).